# How to avoid double-extracting of overlapping patterns in SpaCy with Matcher?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, matcher

I need to extract item combination from 2 lists by means of python Spacy Matcher. The problem is following:
Let us have 2 lists:

```
colors=['red','bright red','black','brown','dark brown']
animals=['fox','bear','hare','squirrel','wolf']
```

I match the sequences by the following code:

```
first_color=[]
last_color=[]
only_first_color=[]
for color in colors:
    if ' ' in color:
        first_color.append(color.split(' ')[0])
        last_color.append(color.split(' ')[1])
    else:
        only_first_color.append(color)
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)

pattern1 = [{"TEXT": {"IN": only_first_color}},{"TEXT":{"IN": animals}}]
pattern2 = [{"TEXT": {"IN": first_color}},{"TEXT": {"IN": last_color}},{"TEXT":{"IN": animals}}]

matcher.add("ANIMALS", None, pattern1,pattern2)

doc = nlp('bright red fox met black wolf')

matches = matcher(doc)

for match_id, start, end in matches:
    string_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]  # Get string representation
    span = doc[start:end]  # The matched span
    print(start, end, span.text)
```

It gives the output:

```
0 3 bright red fox
1 3 red fox
4 6 black wolf
```

How can i extract only 'bright red fox' and 'black wolf'? Should i change the patterns rules or post-process the matches?

Any thoughts appreciate!

Comment: What is `title`?

Comment: Sorry, it was from old code version. Now edited.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You may use [`spacy.util.filter_spans`](https://spacy.io/api/top-level#util.filter_spans):

> Filter a sequence of [Span](https://spacy.io/api/span) objects and remove duplicates or overlaps.
> Useful for creating named entities (where one token can only be part
> of one entity) or when merging spans with [`Retokenizer.merge`](https://spacy.io/api/doc#retokenizer.merge). When
> spans overlap, the (first) longest span is preferred over shorter
> spans.

Python code:

```
matches = matcher(doc)
spans = [doc[start:end] for _, start, end in matches]
for span in spacy.util.filter_spans(spans):
    print(span.start, span.end, span.text)
```

Output:

```
0 3 bright red fox
4 6 black wolf
```

Comment: thanks a lot! It's really elegant solution for the matter. I'm new with spacy and I didn't know about the possibilities of  spacy.util.filter_spans. It worked for me very good.

Comment: In case anyone besides me wants to eliminate nested spans but keep overlapping spans: you can modify the code of [filter_spans](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/d622883a427f7837ce8d3ea5116bbbf1acb7d675/spacy/util.py#L1222) to use an `or` instead of `and` in the `if` statement.

Answer (score 5):

As of spaCy 3.0, the Matcher class now has a greedy filter.

```
matcher.add("ANIMALS", [pattern1,pattern2], greedy="LONGEST")
```

When added to matcher object, this returns

```
0 3 bright red fox
4 6 black wolf
```

See:
https://spacy.io/api/matcher#add

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.